# Why a document less relevant to search query receives higher cosine similarity score?

Tags: python, search, nlp, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

Wile experimenting with TFIDF text search, oddly a document that lacks one of the search query terms receives a higher cosine similarity score.

I get that the term 'ASIC' is less frequent in the corpus than 'cybersecurity' which may explain the higher TF and IDF (and surely the cos. sim.) scores, so the first document outweighs the second, even with the missing 'cybersecurity' term, I'm just not sure if this is really the reason or something may be wrong with my calculation / understanding.

What could be done to rank the second document higher containing both search terms?

Also a wrorking example can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/edmondvarga/kernel46989d3fbc

```
import math, copy
from collections import OrderedDict
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

#The way I "fit" the search query document to the lexicon:

query = ['cybersecurity asic']

cv2 = CountVectorizer()
query_bow = cv2.fit_transform(raw_documents=query).toarray()

vocab = OrderedDict((key, 0) for key, value in sorted(cv1.vocabulary_.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1]))
vec = copy.copy(vocab)

for word, idx in cv2.vocabulary_.items():
  docs_containing_word = 0
  for _doc in stories['bodytext'].values:
    # if re.search(f'\\s{word}\\s', _doc.lower()):
    if word in _doc.lower():
      docs_containing_word += 1
  if docs_containing_word == 0:
    continue
  tf = query_bow[0][idx] / len(vocab)
  numOfDocs = stories.shape[0]
  idf = numOfDocs / docs_containing_word
  vec[word] = tf * idf

#function to calculate cosine similarity

def cosine_sim(vec1, vec2):
  dot_prod = 0
  for i, v in enumerate(vec1):
    dot_prod += v * vec2[i]

  mag_1 = math.sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in vec1]))
  mag_2 = math.sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in vec2]))
  return dot_prod / (mag_1 * mag_2)
```

Results:

```
word "cybersecurity":
present in 38 docs
tf: 5.806189397898159e-05, 
idf: 73.3157894736842
tfidf: 0.004256853595406387

word "asic":
present in 17 docs
tf: 5.806189397898159e-05, 
idf: 163.88235294117646
tfidf: 0.00951531980149663

Doc 1 cosine sim: 0.45333133411924276, missing the term "cybersecurity"

The Australian Securities and Investments Commission (ASIC) published a report on 20 December summarising the four regulatory technology (RegTech) initiatives and events conducted by the ASIC during the financial year (FY) 2018-2019.The ASIC initiatives allowed RegTech developers to showcase the potential for RegTech in the financial services industry, which included software to detect non-compliance with mandatory disclosure requirements and a viable proof-of-concept chatbot that can advise businesses regarding licensing questions.In FY2019-2020, ASIC is planning at least four further RegTech initiatives, focusing on machine-learning and digital record-keeping amongst others.

Doc 2 cosine sim: 0.3032089236374744 with both "ASIC" and "cybersecurity" terms

The Australian Securities and Investments Commission (ASIC) published on 18 December a report on the cyber resilience of firms operating in Australia’s financial markets, following an assessment of firms’ abilities to prepare for, respond to and recover from cybersecurity events.The report also aims to identify new and emerging trends in cybercrime, such as the outsourcing of non-core functions to third parties, which has created difficulties in the management of cybersecurity risks in the supply chain.
```

Comment: Could you share the variable `stories` with us so we will be able to reproduce your results?

Comment: @Anwarvic sure! I've created a working sample on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/edmondvarga/kernel46989d3fbc, here the result is slightly different, now the first match with bot search terms slided to 3rd position

Comment: Relevance is a vague term, and cosine similarity is used as a proxy to define it; but you can't really be sure that this matches 100% to your own understanding of relevance.

Comment: @OliverMason thanks, well that was the same conclusion i ended up with. Maybe a simple BOW vector (with normalised term frequencies) where I would count word overlap using a dot product would give better results in this scenario.